A quote about Alekhine and Capablanca
I came across a tweet in Turkish but could not find the source. It is something like:

You would never know what would come from Alekhine; you would always
know what would come from Capablanca, but you could do nothing about it
anyway.

What is the source?

I don't know either, but the name is Capablanca ("white head"), not Casablanca ("white house", also the name of a Morocco metropolis and the setting of the famous Bergman-Bogart movie).

The quote is often attributed to Emanuel Lasker, though finding the exact original source can be a challenge.
You can find a notable reference to this quote in the book "Capablanca's Hundred Best Games of Chess" by Harry Golombek. In this book, Golombek discusses the contrasting styles of Capablanca and Alekhine. He highlights how Capablanca's clear and methodical play made his moves seem inevitable and unstoppable, while Alekhine's unpredictable and imaginative style posed a different kind of challenge to his opponents.
Golombek attributes the quote to Emanuel Lasker, who was known for his keen commentary on the games of his contemporaries.

I think this may be a remark made by the several-times British champion C. H. o'D Alexander. I cant supply a source, but it is something I heard long ago, and that is how I recall it.
